# how to find repetitive words in each rows in CSV and put into as column name and the next row data as its instances

Tags: python, r, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file containing two column, in first column having dsyn,clnd and gngm repetedly and in next column  having respective disease name or drug name or gene name like below

```
abstract1.csv

> clnd,Melatonin 3 MG
  dsyn,Disease
  dsyn,DYSFUNCTION
  dsyn,Migraine Disorders
  gngm,CD5L wt Allele
  gngm,CD69 wt Allele
  gngm,CLOCK gene
```

I want the output like below shown output

```
> dsyn              clnd                           gngm
Disease             Melatonin 3 MG                 CD5L wt Allele
DYSFUNCTION                                        CD69 wt Allele
Migraine Disorders                                 CLOCK gene
```

Comment: Please share the sample data using `dput` and the expected output

Comment: Are you doing this with R or Python?  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using R, then something like this may work for you.

```
# Read the csv into a data frame
df <- read.csv('PATH.TO.FILE.csv', header = FALSE, col.names = c('V1', 'V2'), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# Split the data frame into a list of data frames based on the unique values in the first column
ldf <- split(df, factor(df$V1))

# Get the maximum number of rows in any data frame
max.rows <- max(unlist(lapply(ldf, nrow)))

# Apply function to each data frame in the list
ldf <- lapply(ldf, function(x){
  # Remove unused factor levels from the data frame
  x <- droplevels(x)

  # Set the column name of the second column to the value of the first column
  colnames(x)[2] <- unique(levels(x$V1))

  # If there are fewer rows than the max, then add empty rows to ensure all data frames have the same length
  if(nrow(x) < max.rows){
    x[c((nrow(x) + 1):max.rows),] <- NA
  }

  # Remove the first column
  x$V1 <- NULL

  # Return the modified data frame
  return(x)
})

# Combine all data frames back into a single data frame
df2 <- do.call(cbind, ldf)
```

Or you could also try this approach using `tidyr` and `dplyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.csv('PATH.TO.FILE.csv', header = FALSE, col.names = c('V1', 'V2'), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

df2 <- df %>% 
       mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
       spread(V1, V2) %>%
       select(-i)

df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df2, sort, na.last = TRUE)) %>% 
       filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) != ncol(.))
```